# Converting Ellipsoidal Heights to GDA2020 Z co-ordinates?

Tags: gda2020

I need to convert UTM 50 X/Ys in GDA2020 at sea level, to GDA94 MGA UTM 50 coordinates.

I've used the  '7-parameter similarity transformation' from the GDA2020TechnicalManualV1.1.1 paper, and this is working well. I get the same results as the example section 3.1.1. ( Happy to supply the Java code if anyone wants).

That is:

```
GDA94 coordinates of Alice Springs (ALIC)
Latitude (DD) Longitude (DD) Ellipsoidal Height (m) -23.6701239 133.8855133 603.3466
X Y Z -4052051.7643 4212836.2017 -2545106.0245
```

is equivalent to;

```
GDA2020 coordinates of Alice Springs (ALIC)
X Y Z -4052052.7379 4212835.9897 -2545104.5898
Latitude (DD) Longitude (DD) Ellipsoidal Height (m) -23.6701101 133.8855216 603.2489
```

My question is how to convert the Ellipsoidal Height, into the Z co-ordinates.

The centre of our area of interest in this case is lat/long -19.82, 119.35, and we can assume everything is at mean sea level.

What would be a suitable Z GDA2020 to feed into the conversion? And how can we calculate it for other surveys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get there with what you've implemented so far. Currently, you're converting between latitude-longitude-ellipsoidal height and 3D Cartesian XYZ coordinates which are earth-centered.

The vertical coordinate reference system in Australia is AHD, Australian Height Datum.

To convert between ellipsoidal heights and the normal-orthometric heights (elevations) in AHD, you need a geoid model. If your horizontal coordinates (latitude-longitude) are on GDA2020, you need [AUSGeoid2020](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/ausgeoid2020).

If the data's using GDA94, you'll need an earlier geoid model like AUSGeoid09. The above linked webpage has several links to various geoid models, discusses the model format, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response.